# Kotlin common library to reuse in multiple MPP

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm setting up a Kotlin multiplatform project so I can reuse common code in multiple platforms for a single app. While building the common code for the app, I've extracted some base classes that I'd like to be able to reuse as a library in *multiple* multiplatform projects. I'm trying to add the library as a dependency in commonMain. There are a couple of things I don't understand.

First of all: is this currently possible?

**If yes:**
The default stdlib-common is a jar file, correct? How come a jar can be referenced as a dependency in commonMain if no Java can be used there? Or is it okay to use a jar compiled from pure Kotlin, as long as it only has Kotlin dependencies?

How do I compile a pure Kotlin jar that can be used in commonMain the same way as stdlib-common is used? Are there any sample build.gradle projects or guides for how this should be packaged?

**If no:**
What options do I otherwise have to reuse code over multiple multiplatform projects, if I want to avoid duplication? Do I actually need to keep all source within the actual commonMain source folder? Can it be linked from another folder if so? I tried adding additional content roots but it didn't seem to work since Gradle controls the configuration and I'm not sure how to add additional content roots in commonMain through Gradle.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, mainly from looking through [this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-1-3-m2-new-multiplatform-projects-model) and looking at [this example](https://github.com/wild-lynx/mpp-lib-dependency). Although some of it might be dated by now, it helped me understand the following:

MPP1 can have another MPP2 as a dependency. [Here](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries) is a list of MPP libraries for reference.

MPP2 needs to generate artifacts for the same set of platforms as it is used in by MPP1.

MPP2 generates platform artifacts along with a [module file](https://blog.gradle.org/gradle-metadata-1.0) where they are described. MPP1 can then use the below configuration. Thanks to the module file, it's not required to explicitly add each platform's corresponding dependency, the dependency only needs to be declared in commonMain.

```
commonMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
        implementation 'com.company:mpp2:1.0'
    }
}
```